# React Native writing to Styles

Tags: css, react-native

quick question.
Is it possible to change the value of an already defined style? such as:
styles.container.backgroundColor?

I get an 'Attempt to write to readonly property' error but this seems crazy that I couldn't change background colors on the fly. Is there a best practice way of doing this that I've missed?

Much appreciated,
a.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `StyleSheet.create`, it generates an immutable object. It does this so that it can just use the stylesheet's ID to communicate back and forth with the native bridge. Making the StyleSheet immutable simplifies that communication.

You can, however, override specific rules in a stylesheet. See the "React Native Fish" project as an example: https://github.com/istarkov/react-native-fish/blob/master/application/common/flake.js

For your use case, I think it'd be something like:

```js
return (
    <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor }]}></View>
);
// this.setState({backgroundColor: "#aaa"});
```

Comment: Perfect, I think I get it now, I'll have to create a class with its own propstyles that can be changed dynamically.

Answer (score 4):

this has been discussed in docs:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html#content

styles changes as per the boolean value of this.state.active

```
<View style={[styles.base, this.state.active && styles.active]} />
```